# Increase Performance of MYSQL QUERY involving unions

Tags: mysql, sql, go, query-performance, sqlperformance

Have a Golang utility which is able to decrease data points per day in a table with historic data.

The records range from 20 to 400 records per day.
totally there are a minimum of 100 million records.

The utility is able to trim it down to n records per day prior to a given date. (n can range from 1 to 300 records per day)

**The method I am using is as follows:**

*STEP 1:*

> CREATE TABLE main_table_tmp LIKE main_table;

*STEP 2:*

> ALTER TABLE main_table_tmp ADD COLUMN timekey INT;

*STEP 3:*

```
INSERT INTO main_table_tmp 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column_name)/((1440/2)*60)) AS timekey 
  FROM main_table
  WHERE column_name <= '2018-01-01' 
  GROUP BY timekey
) m 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * ,0 As timekey FROM main_table where column_name > 'date') ;
```

*STEP 4:*

> ALTER TABLE main_table_tmp DROP COLUMN timekey;
>
> DROP TABLE maintable;
>
> RENAME TABLE maintable_tmp TO maintable;

**I am achieving the above using golang.**

```
func somefuncname(){

  ---- 
  ----
  ----
  q := "CREATE TABLE " + *tablename + "_tmp LIKE " + *tablename + ";"
  rows, err := db.Query(q)
  if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  }
//--ALTER ADD timekey
//--INSERT INTO SELECT *....
//--ALTER DROP timekey ,DROP table and rename

}
```

**The current response time of this query is very slow**

**Some of the Results:**
**Total Records :** 2 million
**Execution Time:** 180 seconds

This is on a 16Gb RAM CPU
It is very slow when it is deployed on a low grade system

**Steps I have took to resolve this:**

1. Looked into indexes of all the tables. Tried removing the index and running the utility. Removing indexes made the utility faster by 5 seconds which is also not much.
2. Executed the utility in stages: if total records crosses more than 1 million then run the utility 1 million at a time

But after all these efforts looks like the main problem is in the query itself.

It is just not fast enough. I just need a way to increase the efficiency of the query

Any help appreciated,
thank you guys!!

Comment: "This is on a 16Gb RAM CPU It is very slow when it is deployed on a low grade system" does this refer to the MySQL server or the machine running this utility? Because the utility is doing al this with `INSERT INTO...SELECT`, the utility itself should use basically no resources, it just waits on MySQL; you'll want to speed up the DB side, probably by making sure your `SELECT` is using good indexes (`EXPLAIN` will tell you) and removing all indexes on the destination and adding them back when the inserts are done.

Comment: You might also trying dumping the `UNION` and just running two separate `INSERT INTO...SELECT`s, one for each query.

Comment: @Adrian All the tables are loaded with minimum of 3 to 4 indexes. I believe the indexes are usually retrieved from memory. This plays a part in the lower end systems and affects execution time. This is as far as I know. Please correct me if I am thinking wrong

Comment: Try to run prepared SQL using only mysql CLI. Is it faster or it's the same? If you can get speed up by using CLI - I consider to think about: a) prepare file with query output, b) reading in golang this file

Comment: The indexes are used on the MySQL server, so that's where you need a lot of memory. The Go tool, based on what you've shown here, should use very very little memory and CPU. All it does is send a query that returns no results and wait for it to finish.

Comment: @Adrian I already had tried removing all indexes and putting it back on after execution. It made the execution faster by just around 5 to 10  seconds which is not much when compared with the total execution time of 180 secs

Comment: we can't answer this question without `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` commands for every table involved in the question/query and without a `EXPLAIN query` output..

Comment: Also seeing `SELECT * ... GROUP BY timekey`  also means 99% out the time the SQL is invalid written, unless MySQL could have used functional dependency..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes I am evading mysql functional dependency by disabling it.
But the query is able to serve its purpose and is accurate . But can this query be altered to make it abide by functional dependancy???. I did not find any other way without having to use the column names of the main table in the query. I want this utility to be universal.

Comment: You mean you disabled sql_mode only_full_group_by i assume you like to play russian roulette because that is what you are doing

Comment: No we cant suggest a rewrite without example data and expected results

Comment: There is too much guessing -- _Please_ provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @AlexYu - The same query will run at the same speed in mysql CLI versus any other client.

Comment: @Prashanth - The query can be modified to abide... -- see my comments on spencer's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are we adding `timekey` and then dropping it? Adding it to an empty table is fast, but dropping it from a table after it's populated, that's like an extra copy of the table. That's unnecessary work, if we don't need it.

We can do a `GROUP BY` on an expression; that expression doesn't have to appear in the SELECT list., for example:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM main_table t
 WHERE t.column_name <= '2018-01-01'
 GROUP 
    BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.column_name)/((1440/2)*60))
```

(Note that this query will cause an error if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is included in sql_mode; that disables a MySQL-specific extension which allows the query to run.)

Without some table definitions (including storage engine, column datatypes, indexes) and without EXPLAIN output, we're just guessing.

But some suggestions:

Drop the secondary indexes on the empty table being populated, and add them after the table is loaded.

I'd avoid the UNION.  Given that one of the SELECT statements has a predicate on `column_name` and the other has a predicate on an entirely different column `date`, we do want to separate SELECT statements.

```
CREATE TABLE main_table_tmp LIKE main_table
;

-- for performance, remove secondary indexes, leave just the cluster index
ALTER TABLE main_table_tmp 
    DROP INDEX noncluster_index_1
  , DROP INDEX noncluster_index_2
  , ...
;

-- for performance, have a suitable index available on main_table 
-- with `column_name` as the leading column
INSERT INTO main_table_tmp 
SELECT h.*
  FROM main_table h
 WHERE h.column_name <= '2018-01-01'
 GROUP 
    BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.column_name)/((1440/2)*60))
;

-- for performance, have a suitable index available on main_table
-- with `date` as the leading column
INSERT INTO main_table_tmp
SELECT c.*
  FROM main_table
 WHERE c.date > '????-??-??'
;

-- add secondary indexes 
ALTER TABLE maint_table_tmp
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX noncluster_index_1 (fee,fi,fo)
  , ADD INDEX noncluster_index_2 (fum)
  , ...
;
```

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion
The column_name is the "date" itself for all.
Have edited the question now! :)

Comment: Instead of `t.*`, spell out the columns, then replace `t.date` with `FLOOR(...)`.  Better yet, convert the `FLOOR` back to a datetime (or whatever) via a multiply and `FROM_UNIXTIME` (or whatever).

Comment: Also, change the other columns to `AVG(t.temp) AS temp`, etc.  And `MIN(id) AS id`.  Etc, etc -- this avoids the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` problem.

Comment: @RickJames: yes, we should enumerate all of the expressions in the SELECT list. But this appears to be an attempt to delete a whole bunch of rows from a table, by creating a new table, copying only the rows to be kept, and then  swapping the tables; given the `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE`  in the same script, I'm okay with using SELECT * and omitting the list of columns from the INSERT.

Comment: @RickJames: i'm totally on board with fixing the issue with the non-determinant columns (non-aggregates in SELECT not in GROUP BY) ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY problem... I did mention this issue in this answer.  As far as how to fix that, I could answer that, but it seems like a different question than the one that was asked. (To fix it properly, I'd need the  PRIMARY KEY or a non-null UNIQUE KEY, and then I could craft the SQL.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - The OP is quiet about the type of data.  If it is meteorological, then min/max/avg makes more sense.  If it is stock quotes, then opening price makes sense.  Etc.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks so much for the solution. I tested it out and the new query strategy was able to increase efficiency. It used to take 44 seconds on a 2 million record table. Now it is able to complete in 25 seconds!!

Comment: @spencer7593 About the type of data, it varies for many tables. I can only have the *id* which can be seen common in some of the tables. So is there any way to make this query work with FULL_GROUP_BY?
It would be excellent if *id* is also not used explicitly.

Comment: @spencer7593 I tried it out in different versions. Here is my [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e30ccc6cee23866c37ee0739009cd107) . Can anything be done to make this work for MYSQL 5.7 and above??

Comment: @RickJames Take a look at the fiddle in the above comment.Can anything be done here?. I am really stuck with the FULL_GROUP_BY here. I cannot use any MAX(temp) or any aggregate functions because I am trying to make this work on a huge DB which has different sets of tables.